# How to do a ridiculously wide plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a long time series of 10000 observations that I want to visualize. The problem is, if I just plot it normally the time-dimension will be squished and none of the fine detail of the time-series that I want to visualize will be apparent. For example:

```
 plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5),type='l')
```

What I would like is to somehow plot the following together side by side in one gigantically long plot without using par(mfrow=c(1,100)). I then want to export this very wide plot and simply scroll across to vizualise the whole series.

```
 plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5)[1:100],type='l')
 plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5)[101:200],type='l')
 plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5)[201:300],type='l')
 .....
```

Eventually I would like to have 3 or 4 of these gigantically wide plots on top of each other with a `par(mfrow=c(4,1))`.

I know that the answer has something to do with the `pin` setting in `par`, but I keep getting `Error in plot.new() : plot region too large`. I'm guessing this has something to do with the interaction of `pin` with the other `par` parameters

***Bonus points are awarded if we can get the pixel height and width exactly right. It is preferable that the plot doesn't skip random pixels due to the export sizing being imperfect.***

**Further bonus points if the image can be encoded in a `.html`. and viewed this way**

Comment: It depends how you're writing this out. Is it to a PDF?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Any image file. png, eps, ..., with a strong preference to small size on disk. png would be nice. Something that can encode to html would also be nice (e.g. png can).

Comment: Does just doing `png(width=10000,height=10000); par(mfrow=....); plot(...); dev.off();` or something similar not give you enough room to fit the really wide plots?

Comment: @thelatemail It's not wide enough. If I go past `width=50000` it says `cairo error 'invalid value (typically too big) for the size of the input (surface, pattern, etc.)`

Comment: I have this exact problem and the solutions listed here do not seem to work.  I'm an R beginner in RStudio.
In my case, I need to introspect over a year of hourly measurements of weather data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative that you might consider is svg, which will produce something of better quality than png/jpeg in any case.

Something like

```
svg(width = 2000, height = 7)
par(mfrow=c(4,1), mar = c(4, 4, 0, 2))
for (i in 1:4){
    plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5),type='l', 
         bty = "l", xaxs = "i")
}
dev.off()
```

will produce a very wide plot, just over 1MB in size, which renders quite nicely in Chrome.

Note the width and height are in inches here.

**P.S.** svg also offers the potential for interactive graphics. Just seen a nice example allowing the user to select a region of a long time series to zoom in on, see Figure 22 in [Dynamic and Interactive R Graphics for the Web: The gridSVG Package](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/gridSVG/gridsvg.pdf), a draft paper by Paul Murrell and Simon Potter.

Comment: svg is a vector format, so I think the answer to your question is arbitrary.

Comment: If you open the generated svg file in a text editor, you will see the dimensions specified as `width="144000pt" height="504pt"`, so 72 points per inch. I tried editing this to `width="144000px" height="504px"` which seemed to work okay, but I don't know if this is a good idea!

Comment: Have you found that it's laggy when you open it with Chrome?

Comment: It's fine for me with Chrome, but slow on Firefox

Comment: I'm using RStudio, and using this code produces the error: "Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device).  It also does not produce the SVG output.  It does create an SVG file but it is empty.

Comment: You get that error if you call `dev.off()` when only the RStudio plot window is open, e.g. because you have not opened the svg device, or you have already run `dev.off()` once, closing the svg device. Make sure you run the `svg()` call to open the svg device before running the plotting code.

Comment: Also, make sure you open the created file (`Rplot001.svg`) with a browser, you may need to right-click and select to open with another application than the default e.g. to open with Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

It could be a Cairo-specific problem, or it could be a lack of RAM on your machine.  The following code works fine for me on a Windows 7 machine with 8GB RAM.

```
png("wide.png", width = 1e5, height = 500)
plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5),type='l')
dev.off()
```

If I change the width to `1e6` pixels, then R successfully creates the file (it took about a minute), but no image viewing software that I have available can display an image that large.

Comment: Cairo limits the width/height to 32767 pixels. A width of 1e4 should be fine for plotting 1e4 data points though, and will help keep the file size down.

Comment: I'm probably looking for around 150,000 pixels but I get this error: `> dev.off()
Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels
*** glibc detected *** /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000278f950 ***` Then it'll dump all this "backtrace" stuff.

Comment: Please can you add the exact code that you are using to create the plot file to your question, along with you OS and and the version of R  that you are running.

Comment: @RichiCotton Actually PNG works, only JPG doesn't work for that many pixels.

Comment: Well, JPGs are more suited to storing photos than plots.  Use PNG or a vector format.

Answer (score 1):

I would go on some alternative route.  First of all,  what exactly is the point of viewing the entire plot at hi-res?  If you're searching for some sort of anomalies or irregularities, well, that's what data processing is for :-) . Think about something like finding all`x > 3sigma`, or doing an FFT, etc.

Next, if you really want to examine the whole thing by eye, how about writing some R-TclTK code or using `dynamicGraph` or `iplots` or `zoom` to produce an interactive graph that you can scroll thru "live."

ETA: IIRC  RStudio has tools for interactive graph scrolling and zoom as well.

Comment: @user2763361 The `zoom` package works well with the basic `plot` graphs. It lets you modify the X and Y  scales (both range and resolution) interactively.  I believe `iplots` does as well.

Comment: Viewing the whole thing is important for me. I need to see the precise evolution of the time-series for every single data point. Could you give some examples about what you recommended? Also I want to put it in a `html` report or something that isn't conditional on having R open at the time.